# Scrollable list of custom items for Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm attempting to display a "list" of things in a simple/learning Android app.  I'm using "list" in quotes, because I'm unsure of the correct terminology w/ Android.  Everything I read online tends to focus on string/text-based lists of items, but that's not what I'm after.

I'm an Android novice, but I know enough to write simple apps w/ Linear and/or Relative layouts.  However, now I'm attempting to display ~100 items in a vertically-scrolling list, but I want each of the items to adhere to a common layout I've defined.

Here is a sample picture in case I'm not describing this well.
[image]

Say I define a sampleLayout.xml file w/ an ImageView and TextView (to contain the IMG and descriptive text for each row).

Which Android object(s) should I use to display a list of SampleLayout items?  If it matters, I'm not yet concerned w/ interacting w/ these items or adding/removing items; I'm mainly looking to just build this list onCreate.

Comment: You'll want to look into building a custom `BaseAdapter` and using it to populate a list using the "ViewHolder" design pattern. Search for both and you'll find plenty of resources for how to do it. You can also go with the `RecyclerView` as mentioned in the answer below. Both are viable and widely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to build a large scrollable list of items is [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).  There are a ton of tutorials out there about it.